# webpack/webpack-dev-server/react shows directory listing when it should show app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Using a simple starter react app with webpack-dev-server, it works on one computer but not another.

#### Tried / Info

- Both computers are windows 10
- Using vscode/git bash on both
- node -v `9.11.1` on both
- npm -v `5.6.0` on both
- yarn -v `1.5.1` on both
- Tried both yarn and npm
- Deleted all global npm modules in ~/appdata/roaming/npm on both computers

---

#### Process:

This is not my repo but a simple one that works for testing.
Comes from awesome [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4&t=1232s).

`git clone https://github.com/bradtraversy/react_webpack_starter
cd react_webpack_starter
npm install
npm start (runs webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot)`

---

#### Expected Result (1 computer):

Browser opens with "My React App"

---

#### Actual Result (1 computer):

- Directory listing instead of app, shown [here](https://gyazo.com/7e3fe4677d8285a396ca7e3715255c8d).
- This indicates webpack --contentBase issue, but when I set it to src/, the index.html file is shown, but it appears like no react code is processed.
- terminal output [here](https://gyazo.com/3ac433cba0e31c5f4a00fbfeed71befb)

---

#### Initial Rambling

I don't know what the issue is on the env with the non-working computer. Symptoms indicate it is not the repo or code, but has to be in how my env. Spent 6 hours working on this issue on the computer where it fails. Though it was me being an idiot somewhere, just to have it work on a different computer. Anyone have any ideas on what the difference in environments could be?

---

#### Solution:

As per [Peter Liang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973833/peter-liang)'s suggestion,

- I tried cloning repo into C:\testtest and it worked.
- I tried cloning repo into C:\test test and it failed (showed directory listing).

Webpack-dev-server doesn't seem to be able to deal with paths with spaces.

Added an issue to webpack-dev-server github [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1375)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem and it turned out that the name of my parent directory was the culprit. My original path was "C:\React Apps\react-boilerplate", then I changed it to "C:\reactapps\react-boilerplate" and it worked.

Comment: thanks :)
my username had spaces in it, updated question with solution